# Find the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(14565695, 61489)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $m,n\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\,\gcd(14565695, 61489) = m\cdot 14565695 + n\cdot 61489.$

I used the Euclidean Algorithm to show the gcd $=1.$ What way is there to solve such a question? 
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Reverse reverse!

Comment: I thought so!
I shall try it now

Comment: For a systematic way, there is the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you crash, Bernard, I learned a lot today.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. This will give you exactly the decomposition you are looking for. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm for details.

The answer is $m=-19,793$ and $n=468,8624$

Comment: You seem to know about how to find the answer...maybe give it a shot then so your answer is a real answer?

Comment: OK, I added the answer!

Comment: @user1512023  You should fill in the details to explain how you arrived at your answer.

Comment: I just learned the euclidean Algorithms and it worked perfectly fine.